# Looking for Sinhala-English, English-Sinhala dictionary that includes IPA

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, sinhala

I'm interested in learning Sinhala, the language most widely spoken across Sri Lanka. Mainly, I am looking for resources: a Sinhala-English, English-Sinhala dictionary that includes IPA phonetics, for example, would be a good start.

So far the only source I have at hand is Dileep Chandralal's "Sinhala" (Benjamins 2010, 9789027238153), which is more of a reference text for linguists rather than for language learners; yet it has already helped me learn some grammar and pronunciation; the IPA style translations in the text are very useful.

I have done some online searching to find more but haven't been able to vet any of the resources for quality etc. If anyone knows of any further resources, I'd be really grateful.